# easiest way to log and save basic GPU stats in Unreal Engine?

Tags: gpu, profiling, unreal-engine5

I need to log the basic GPU stats (computation times) in a file while testing in the unreal engine editor so that I can analize them afterwards.
What would be the easiest way of doing that? I'm using UE 5.1

- no preference for blueprint, the solution can employ blueprint or not.
- I don’t need to log the synchronized events (it is ok if they are added too, i just dont have to have them). I just need the plain basic stats as time goes by.

Any constructive feedback is appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unreal ships with a powerful profiler called Unreal Insights, which can be used to record and analyze GPU processes as well. It is a standalone tool which you can attach to your Editor session when testing.

You can find it at `Engine/Binaries/Win64/UnrealInsights.exe` (relative to engine install directory). It saves data to `Engine/Programs/UnrealInsights/Saved/TraceSessions` (also relative to engine install dir).

[Here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/TestingAndOptimization/PerformanceAndProfiling/GPU/) is an in-depth documentation.

Comment: do you know a reliable way to see the average number of triangles drawn during a selected period? or over a whole run?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't done that specifically, can't really offer advice.